# Image over image onClick event for image mapping

Tags: html, image, events, onclick, mapping

I have written some code for an image I am mapping. When I click on a box that I've mapped[MAC 2311] within the original image, I have an onClick event to where I call a function in which I would like to append an image, more specifically an X, over the original box that I just clicked, but my onClick event isn't working. Here is my code for the function and my fiddle with full code. Click on the box marked MAC 2311 calculus I to test my onClick

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function myAction(where) { 
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "http://i67.tinypic.com/2dvo8qp.jpg"; 
  img.height = 75; 
  img.width = 113;
  img.style.top=700;
  img.style.right=100;
  where.parentNode.appendChild(img);
}



</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L04yjr88/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because it has script tags in the javascript section, by the way

Comment: An image as child of an area ? I'm not sure this can work.